# proof by induction to prove $E[X^{2n}]=(2n-1)(2n-3) . . . 5.3.1$

Tags: measure-theory, induction

X is standard normal, use proof by induction to prove for all $n\in N$ that $E[X^{2n}]=(2n-1)(2n-3) . . . 5.3.1$

I would appreciate any tips or help on how to prove this, if anyone has time. I assume I need to find a case of some E[x^y] where this is true then use induction to prove it for all? very confused and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Prove $E[X^2]=1$ directly (by taking an integral). For the induction, see if you can write $E[X^{2(n+1}]$ in terms of $E[X^{2n}]$ using integration by parts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I took the integral: integral_(-∞)^∞ (x^2 e^(-x^2/2))/sqrt(2 π) dx = 1 I am confused on your second comment, and why writing it in terms of $E[X2(n+1] $ helps

Comment: I am able to write $E[X^{2(n+1)}]$ in terms of $E[X^{2n}]$ by I.B.P like you suggest and find it equals  $E[X^{2(n-1)}]$, where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment: integration by parts with $u=x^{2n+1}$ and $v = -e^{-x^2/2}$ yields

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2(n+1)} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx
= [-x^{2n+1} e^{-x^2/2}]_{x=-\infty}^\infty + (2n+1)\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n} e^{-x^2/2}.$$

Comment: I follow but don't understand what to do next. I see: 

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2(n+1)} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx
= 0 + (2n+1)*E[x^{2n}]$$

Comment: From my work above, we have $E[X^{2(n+1)}] = (2n+1) E[X^{2n}]$.

Answer (score 0):

Do a u-sub and you will see a gamma function.  What can you do with this?